# Update the Navbar every 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I want to get live updates from my django server and update the view accordingly.

There is a navbar at the top that needs to be updated after every 5 seconds ( or so )

The code is :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var Scores = Backbone.Collection.extend({
      url: '//localhost:8000/api/live_scores'
    });


    var Ticker = Backbone.View.extend({
      el: '.page',
      render: function () {
        var self = this;
        var scores = new Scores();
        scores.fetch({
          success: function (scores) {
            var template = _.template($('.ticker').html());
            var result = template({scores: scores.models});
            self.$el.html(result);
          }
        },this);
      }
    });


    var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            "": 'home'
        }
    });

    var ticker = new Ticker();
    var router = new Router;
    router.on('route:home', function() {
      ticker.render();       <------------Earlier it was this
    });


    Backbone.history.start();
    setInterval(ticker.render, 1000); <------------ Changed to this
});
```

### Note :

---

The above code doesn't work, cause once the view renders it in , next time when setInterval calls the callable ( here `ticker.render`) , the element is no longer available.

### Problem 2 :

This ticker needs to be on all the pages, so what should I do to keep it on all the pages. 
 But the router wouldn't route it on a different page.
 **Solution 1 :**  add `ticker.render()` on all the routes. 
  **Cons :**  It would get difficult to manage.

Thanks.

Comment: _"the element is no longer available"..._ Which element?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your interval callback probably doesn't work because it's bound to an outer scope. Use `.bind(this)` to bind it to the local scope where the `ticker` variable is defined.

```
setInterval(ticker.render.bind(this), 5000);
```

Secondly, this interval behaviour should be part of the view itself. In backbone it's ok encapsulate logic and behaviour of a controller (in an MVC pattern) inside your views.

A proper place to start your interval is when the view first renders but depending on your app you could away with starting it inside the `initialize` method. I suggest that you use a flag-like variable inside your `initiliaze` method or constructor like `this.hasBeenRendered = false` and then on first `render()` call start your interval and mark the flag as `true` like so:

```
render: function() {
  if(!this.hasBeenRendered) {
    this.startTicker(); // something you like to start the interval
    this.hasBeenRendered = true;
  }
  ...
}
```